# \boldsymbol does not boldify \cdot

Tags: fourier, boldsymbol

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,fge,stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ushort}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{BOONDOX-calo}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrsf{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}

\pagestyle{empty}

\appto\normalsize{\belowdisplayshortskip=\belowdisplayskip}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\boldsymbol}

\begin{document}

$\vec f(\vec x)\vec\cdot\vec f(\vec y)=\vec x\vec\cdot\vec y$

\end{document}
```

If I don’t include the fourier package, \cdot gets bolded. However I really want to use the fourier package, as well as have bolded \cdot’s. Can anybody help?

Comment: The `fourier` package does not offer a boldface math symbol font.

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck, because `fourier` doesn't offer a bold math symbol font.

You can use `erewhon` for the text and `newtxmath` with the `utopia` option for math.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\boldsymbol}
\newcommand{\bcdot}{\bm{\cdot}}

\begin{document}

$\vec{f}(\vec{x})\bcdot\vec{f}(\vec{y})=\vec{x}\bcdot\vec{y}$

$f(x)\cdot f(y)=x\cdot y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If switching to `lualatex` is an option for you, you could use the `fourier-otf` fonts which provide a (limited) support for bold maths. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{fourier-otf}
\setmathfont{Erewhon-Math-Bold}[version=bold,bold-style=ISO]
\begin{document}
$f(x)\cdot f(y) = x \cdot y$

$\symbf{f(x)\cdot f(y) = x \cdot y}$

{\mathversion{bold}$f(x)\cdot f(y) = x  \cdot y$}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be loading `bm` package will help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,fge,stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ushort}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{BOONDOX-calo}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrsf{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}
\usepackage{bm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\appto\normalsize{\belowdisplayshortskip=\belowdisplayskip}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\boldsymbol}

\begin{document}

$\vec f(\vec x)\vec\cdot\vec f(\vec y)=\vec x\vec\cdot\vec y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just adding that package isn’t working for me, unfortunately.